# how to loop through a collection and find something in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and ruby.

I have a has_many association between user and store

below is what I do:

```
@user = User.find_by_userid_and_password("someuser", "12345")
=> #<User id: 1, userid: "someuser", password: "12345", 
created_at: "2010-01-25 00:00:00", updated_at: "2010-01-25 00:00:00"> 
@user.stores
=> [#<Store id: 3, store_id: 3, store_name: "New Store 2", 
created_at: "2010-01-25 00:00:00", updated_at: "2010-01-25 00:00:00">, 
 #<Store id: 5, store_id: 5, store_name: "Store 14th and M", 
 created_at: "2010-01-25 00:00:00", updated_at: "2010-01-25 00:00:00">]
```

so basically i am first authenticating the user and then getting all the stores that a user belongs to. For that I get a list back.  In that list of hashes i want to find out if anything is there with `store_id == 4`.

sequentially I do:

```
@user.stores.first.store_id==4
false
@user.stores.second.store_id==4
false
```

how can i make this in a loop? and is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Rails,

Your best approach here is probably not to use a loop, but to chain a find to your first finder.

For example:

`@user.stores.find(store_id)`

This will leverage the db and be much faster.

Check out the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

If you do want to loop you do something like the following

```
@user.stores.each do |store|
  @my_store = store if store.id == store_id
end
```

or

`@my_store = @user.stores.select{|s| s.id == store_id}`

or

`@contains_store = @user.stores.include?{|s| s.id == store_id}`

Good luck,

Comment: Thanks. if i do `@user.stores.find(6)` since 6 is not one of the id's it returns an error. How would I put this in a if condition then? `if @user.stores.find(6) != nil ...` is that ok?

Comment: You can do find_by_id(6) which will return a array (no error will be thrown) and then check for nil.  @user.stores.find_by_id(6).first.nil?

Comment: Since nil is false in Ruby, you can just do `if @user.stores.find(6)...`, you don't have to manually compare to nil since you're just running with a true/false expression.